curl version question
I installed the curl library today to try the examples at, https://curl.se/libcurl/c/example.html. When I try to compile the headerapi example, I get headerapi.c: In function ‘main’: headerapi.c:61:8: error: ‘CURLHE_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘CURLUE_OK’? 61 |     if(CURLHE_OK == curl_easy_header(curl, "Content-Type", 0, CURLH_HEADER,.
I also found that in the docs that the curl_easy_header was added in the 7.83.0 version.
What my sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev gave me is 7.81.0.
So what are my options? Do I wait to see if the package gets updated, do try to manually install somehow?

So, are you using Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)? one option might be to upgrade to 24.04 (noble) which has libcurl4-gnutls-dev 8.5.0

if you need a very specific version of CURL for something I would use their official git repo. https://curl.se/dev/source.html

Just upgrade to 24.04 and the problem should be solved

Thanks all, I am using 22.04 (jammy), it's also in wsl. From what I have found so far is that this is the highest version wsl supports. I will have to look more at using the git repo.

@Michael Munns: actually Ubuntu 24.04.1 is installable via the Microsoft Store. Just ooen the Microsoft Store on your Windows machine, type "Ubuntu" and you will see 24.04.1 among other Ubuntu releases.
